# Disable Genre Art in iTunes 11?

Tags: macos, itunes, preferences

New iTunes bumps up the font size and adds Genre images to Genre column view. I make custom Genres for sorting and don't need the visual hinting. Anyone know how/if I can disable this? I'm not able to find anything.

Otherwise I guess I'll just be using the Song view. I really liked the three column Genre sort up until now. :(

[image: Boring Genre Art]

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the genre-*.jpg files in the application bundle. iTunes will use the cover art of tracks for the genres though.

[image]

It also breaks the code signature and could be overridden by updates.

Comment: I'm not all that fond of the generic Apple or empty icons and I'd prefer to save space but I appreciate the step in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use album artwork for genre artwork. To do this I edited `genres.plist` in iTunes resources folder using `Property List Editor`, under 'Root' I deleted 'entries' which deletes all default itunes album artworks associative preference.

Another method is adding an

```
    exactStringMatch - Boolean - Check
```

method to whichever 'Item' I prefer to change. This method is used for other genres by iTunes.  This method works for genres which don't have an exact genre matching name.

I suggest saving a copy of this `plist` prior to making any changes to it.

Comment: Nice solution. I'll give it a try and report back.